# $("#but0_0").attr(...) works but $(hid).attr(...) does not work when hid === "#but0_0"

Tags: javascript, jquery

On Safari 4.0, I have a check that prints "????" if hid === "#but0_0"

Works:

```
$("#but0_0").attr("onmousedown",function(){alert("Aha!");});
```

Doesn't work:

```
var id = "but"+y+"_"+x;
var hid = "#"+id;
if (hid === "#but0_0") console.debug("????");
$(hid).attr("onmousedown",function(){alert("Aha!");});
```

The console shows "????" so the code is getting hit and the variable is "the same" (from === string compare point of view) as the string literal but apparently jQuery's $() operator knows the difference?

I have 30 divs to manipulate and I need to compute the id of the div at run time. Any ideas? It's probably something simple like pulling out a "string" from a "String" or some such [JavaScript stupidity](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/2005-May/000782.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the following a shot:

```
$(hid).live('mousedown', function() {alert("Aha!");});
```

if your elements are created dynamically.

Comment: Your comment below did the trick: since the elements were created dynamically I needed to use elem.live("onmousedown",...)

Answer (score 1):

Strange that that's the case.

Why aren't you using [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind) to attach your events?

```
$(hid).bind('mousedown', function () { /* something */ });
```

Comment: I agree about binding his events.  You could also use $(hid).live('mousedown', function() {}); if your elements are created dynamically.

Comment: Updated my previous answer with .live if you'd like to accept that :)